# Difference between " The vase was sold at 300 dollars." vs " The vase was sold for 300 dollars."

Tags: prepositions

To me, the first sentence seems to mean the vase was sold at an auction whreas the second sentence was sold at a store.

As a non-native speaker, 
it's so confusing which preposition is more appropriate for the price.

Also, I think the second sentence  more likely to be used  than the first one.

Am I right?
Is there any subtle difference between these two?

Answer (score 4):

> The vase was sold at $300.

This is typical use at an auction, where the actual selling price is determined by the competing bidders. It is normal to use **at** here to emphasize that, from a spectrum of possible prices, *this* is the price **at which** the item sold.

> The vase was sold for $300.

This is the most common use, and is typical in non-auction settings, where the seller sets a price. Even if the list price was $350 and some negotiation was done, it is normal to say that it sold **for** a price.

Note that these uses are not exclusive; one could use either one in either situation, but these are the more common uses.

Comment: Agreed, although instead of *spectrum* I would say it's the *mark **at which** the object was sold*, since (normally) auction prices only go up.

Comment: There is a range of possible prices, from the minimum bid to (theoretically) infinity. That the bids only increase does not change this, although each bid reduces the remaining options.

Comment: Sure, and it's a minor distinction that I only mention because when we use the word "spectrum" we say where someone "falls **on** that spectrum" -- which is to say there is no directional component.  It may be easier to visualize an auction as a rising value that stops **at** the point where no one wants to bid any higher.